# What could cause an error in Windows 7 debugger tools installation?

Tags: windows-7, windows, debug

My computer, a Windows 7 Dell laptop, has been suffering sudden restarts every so often these days. It's most commonly seen through a hesitation to re-connect to wifi after being asleep for a long while, unresponsiveness of every program, and eventually, a complete restart. The "Windows has recovered from an unexpected shutdown" popup says this is a BlueScreen event, while, again, no blue screen happens. I learned that I could open the .DMP files using Windows Debugger, and while trying to install them from the Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4, I encountered an error in installation. Here is the log:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/14pl0Tx5zaTupg-UZPzZQIvs1FHfi3D3G-nUNywZpR8g/edit?usp=sharing

What could cause this to happen, and is there anything i can do to fix my problems?

EDIT: It now likes to beep. It was beeping for a while when it restarted this evening.

Comment: use the Win8.1 SDK, which also works for Windows 7: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891

Comment: "It now likes to beep. It was beeping for a while when it restarted this evening." - This indicates a hardware failure.  To understand what the failure is exactly, check your manual, or contact Dell for support.